# SSRS Report Server Database

Tags: reporting-services

All:

I am looking for the table that houses this data, especially the "Comments" field. But, it's not straight forward to me. Does anyone have a SQL?

Thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is held in the following table:

```
ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
```

in the `ExtensionSetting` column.

It's stored as XML so you'll need to parse the bits you want.

Comment: Thank you, Alan Schofield. I see my comments in this field.